# Strictly spy method argument in PHPUnit

Tags: phpunit, spy

I have this spy in a test:
`$subject->expects( $this->once() )->method( 'send_json_success' )->with( $expected );`

`$expected` is an array and one of the items of this array should be set to `0`.

Instead is currently set to an empty string, which is the source of the problem I'm fixing.
I want to make sure the test fails when the item is set to an empty string, but I can't find how to tell PHPUnit to strictly check the array is exactly the same as `$expected`.

I can't use `$this->same()` because the method does not return anything: I need to test the method is called with the right arguments, instead.

Comment: I don't know if is possible with PHPUnit but it is possible with Phake (a php testing framework library) with the Method Parameter Matchers. check it in the doc [here](http://phake.readthedocs.io/en/2.1/method-parameter-matchers.html?highlight=capture#parameter-capturing). Let me know

Comment: This sounds interesting @Matteo. I'll see if I can get some answer which does not require adding the nth framework to my tests library :) Otherwise. I'll give a try to Phake.

Comment: Of course @Andrea, can you post a failing PHPUnit test of your problem so is more simple to try to solve?

Comment: @Matteo I was about to do so, but `@damien-flament` answer is exactly what I needed. Thanks for the help, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the [API documentation of the *with()* method](https://damienflament.github.io/phpunit-mock-objects-api-docs/4.0.0/PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Builder_ParametersMatch.html#method_with), you can use a [PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint](https://damienflament.github.io/phpunit-api-docs/6.0/PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint.html) object.

A [PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_IsIdentical](https://damienflament.github.io/phpunit-api-docs/6.0/PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_IsIdentical.html) object is used to [implement the TestCase::assetSame() method](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/5.7/src/Framework/Assert.php#L1444).

So, it should be:

```php
<?php

use PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_IsIdentical;

// Test case class...

$subject->expects($this->once())
        ->method('send_json_success')
        ->with(new PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_IsIdentical($expected));
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed @damien-flament. I did search in the API documentation, but I've clearly missed what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: The links to the API documentation I provided point to the API documentation I generated. There isn't any officialy published PHPUnit API documentation.

Comment: That maybe explains why you didn't found it.